# AWS Athena (Presto) - how to format Timestamp to Date Format?

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, presto, amazon-athena

I have a column in Athena with Timestamp Data Type and format is: `2019-08-28 00:00:00.000`

How to format it to Date format using SQL to be:
`DD-MON-YYYY`

Thanks.

Comment: See https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#date_format (Athena is based on .172)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH test AS (
  SELECT '2019-08-28 00:00:00.000' AS str
)
SELECT format_datetime(cast(str AS timestamp), 'dd-MM-YYYY')
FROM test
```

Result:

```
    _col0
1   28-08-2019
```